# How to submit tasks to concurrent.futures ThreadPool executor and return a reply immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I am using concurrent.futures' ThreadPoolExecutor to process some tasks concurrently. **I want to submit the tasks, then return a reply immediately while the tasks get completed in the background.**

The code looks like this:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def main_flow():
    do_some_tasks()
    process_pending_messages()
    do_another_task()

def process_pending_messages():
    messages = get_pending_messages()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(process_msg_in_background, message) for message in messages]
    return 'Tasks have been started in the background'
```

I want to start `do_another_task()` without waiting for all the futures to be evaluated. From what I can see, in `process_pending_messages()`, I'm only submitting the tasks and not waiting on the results of any of the futures. But currently, only after all the submitted tasks are completed, does `do_another_task()` starts executing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you get the output "Tasks have been started" immediately or only after all tasks are completed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ThreadPoolExecutor with context manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48704976/threadpoolexecutor-with-context-manager)

Comment: It's the context manager.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yeah, it does! I was unfortunately not aware that the context manager makes it a blocking call.